# hg add not properly detecting binary files

Tags: mercurial

I have a file that should be added as binary but currently is not. 
Is there a way I can force hg add the file as binary?

The file is an image that is corrupted (on purpose) for a test case.

Update: The problem in particular is that I have a patch file, so when I apply the patch it does not apply the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [its documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles), Mercurial does nothing special for binary vs. text files.  So you don't need to do anything special either, other than refraining from running diffs on them.

Comment: The problem is that I have a patch file so when you apply the patch you get different data.

Comment: Patch files do have limitations.  For example they don't include file modes (e.g. the executable bit on *nix).  I'm not sure a patch file for a binary makes a whole lot of sense.  How about using an `hg bundle` instead?

Answer (score 1):

As John says Mercurial doesn't differentiate between binary and text files internally.  It does display them differently in diff/patch output, and it provides binary-usable diffs for files the output filter thinks might be binary if you use the `--git` option (for git-style diffs).  When decided whether or not to show a file as binary (show, not store) it bases the decision on whether or not there's a NUL (0x00) byte in the file.  Try to get one in there if it really matters.  Alternately consider sending a bundle (`hg bundle`) rather than a diff.